# C# SQL Server 2022 insert into too slow

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, insert, sql-insert

I created a simple table and inserted one thousand rows of data, but it took 10 seconds to insert only 1000 rows. Is this a normal insertion speed? It seems unusually slow. What could be the cause of this issue?

**Create Table**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DB](
    [CODE] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [DATE] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DB] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_DB_DATE]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DATE]
GO
```

**Insert Data**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 1000; i < 2000; i++)
  {
    string query = $"INSERT INTO dbo.DB(CODE) VALUES('CHOCO{i}')";
    SqlExecuteNonQuery(query);
  }
}
private bool SqlExecuteNonQuery(string query)
{
  try
  {
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
      conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return false;
  }
  finally
  {
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      conn.Close();
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: If you are doing 1000 inserts of 1 row each, that will be *far* slower than 1 insert with 1000 rows. SQL Server can easily produce 1000 rows in a single batch, in truth, why not do it there? Also, you really should be parametrising, not injecting. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: It's entirely possible that various exceptions are being thrown - you're swallowing exceptions without even logging them, and ignoring the return value. I would strongly advise simply removing the `catch` block, and changing your method to be void.

Comment: Take a look to [SqlBulkCopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75613152/c-sharp-sql-server-2022-insert-into-too-slow). Also you are opening/closing the connection for every record, that's very inefficient.

Comment: The inserts should be faster, IMHO, but the main reason it's slow is that each insert is an individual transaction, which requires a physical write to the transaction log. Performance will depend much only your storage subsystem. You'll get much better performance using SqlBulkCopy, a single set-based insert statement, or you could start a transaction, insert rows, and commit.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to be slow as you are inserting rows one by one. It will be better to pass the data to SQL Server stored procedure like XML, JSON or CSV like format. Then parse this data and put it in temporary table, perform some validations if needed and then insert the data at once:

```
INSERT INTO table
SELECT *
FROM #table
```

Comment: Or as a table valued parameter.

Comment: @DaleK Sure,  but the table valued parameter is kind of slow when you are working with large data. It's generally table variable. I avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought your problem was that you were opening your connection for each of the rows.

Than I did a simple Test Program but it looks like you are right, it takes around 10s =(.
Edit: I remade my tests on a machine on the same network as the SQL Server Machine, the results were much better (more bellow)

Also, you should parametrize your query. ;)

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var list = Enumerable.Range(1000, 1000).ToList();

        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        sw.Restart();
        NormalOpeningConnectionEachTime(list);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        NormalUsingSameConnection(list);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        BulkCopy(list);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        sw.Restart();
        MultipleValues(list);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        return 1;
    }
}

private static void NormalOpeningConnectionEachTime(IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO dbo.DB(CODE) VALUES (@code)";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            try
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", i);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void NormalUsingSameConnection(IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    var query = "INSERT INTO dbo.DB(CODE) VALUES (@code)";

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code", SqlDbType.Int));
        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            cmd.Parameters[0].Value = i;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

private static void BulkCopy(IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    using (var table = new DataTable())
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString))
    {
        table.Columns.Add("CODE");

        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.[DB]";
        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 1000;
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
        }

        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(i);
        }

        //Attention - At this point the table has all data, but you could WriteToServer when the numberOfRows is more than BatchSize, so to not overload memory (clearing the rows after).
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
    }
}

private static void MultipleValues(IEnumerable<int> list)
{
    void Execute(List<SqlParameter> parameters)
    {
        var query = $"INSERT INTO dbo.DB(CODE) VALUES {(string.Join(",", parameters.Select(x => $"({x.ParameterName})")))}";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            foreach (var s in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(s);
            }

            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
    foreach (var i in list)
    {
        parameters.Add(new SqlParameter($"@code{i}", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = i });

        //Parameter limit is 1000
        if (parameters.Count >= 1000)
        {
            Execute(parameters);
            parameters.Clear();
        }
    }

    if (parameters.Any())
    {
        Execute(parameters);
    }
}
```

The results were (in ms)

A) Using the same network

| # | EachTime | SameConnection | BulkCopy | MultipleValues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1182 | 489 | 252 | 39 |
| 2 | 891 | 503 | 13 | 44 |
| 3 | 876 | 497 | 13 | 34 |
| 4 | 870 | 629 | 13 | 44 |
| 5 | 879 | 549 | 12 | 37 |
| 6 | 888 | 604 | 12 | 43 |
| 7 | 890 | 561 | 18 | 40 |
| 8 | 889 | 518 | 12 | 35 |
| 9 | 868 | 534 | 12 | 34 |
| 10 | 868 | 541 | 18 | 34 |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| Average | 910 | 543 | 38 | 38 |

B) Over the Internet

| # | EachTime | SameConnection | BulkCopy | MultipleValues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10431 | 10108 | 41 | 65 |
| 1 | 10235 | 10247 | 39 | 69 |
| 2 | 10364 | 9753 | 36 | 82 |
| 3 | 10025 | 9981 | 47 | 67 |
| 4 | 10105 | 9935 | 41 | 64 |
| 5 | 9877 | 10241 | 40 | 64 |
| 6 | 10519 | 10517 | 34 | 65 |
| 7 | 10441 | 11246 | 45 | 64 |
| 8 | 10350 | 10318 | 43 | 66 |
| 9 | 10605 | 10630 | 40 | 71 |
| ------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| Average | 10295 | 10297 | 40 | 67 |

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rebuild-index?

If you have more data then use bulk insert for better performance.

Regards,